# Checking keyDown event.modifierFlags yields error

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Im subclassing NSTextView and overriding keyDown. I want to detect command-key-combinations. Command-L, for example.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html) indicates that you simply **and** the modifier flags (in the passed NSEvent) with NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.

When I do so:

```
let ck = NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask
```

I receive an odd error:

```
Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to two 'NSEventModifierFlags' operands.
```

What's the deal? This is swift 2.0, xcode 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Apple's documentation indicates that you simply **and** the modifier flags

The documentation is still referring to C and Objective-C.  Swift uses [`OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html), which does not use bitwise operators for checking flags.

Instead, use the `contains()` method to check for one or more flags:

```
    if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) {
        NSLog("command key down")
    }

    if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.AlternateKeyMask) {
        NSLog("option key down")
    }

    if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains([.CommandKeyMask, .AlternateKeyMask]) {
        NSLog("command and option keys down")
    }
```

To check for a single key, use `intersect` to filter out any unwanted flags, then use `==` to check for a single flag:

```
    let modifierkeys = theEvent.modifierFlags.intersect(.DeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask)

    if modifierkeys == .CommandKeyMask {
        NSLog("Only command key down")
    }
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

NSEventModifierFlags is an optionSet in Swift 2.0. You can use contain method to check it contains the command modifier key

```
override func keyDown(theEvent:NSEvent) {
    if theEvent.characters == "l" && theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) {
        print("command-L pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: That wasn't me that downvoted you. Anyhow, why did you change from theEvent.modifierFlags.contains to theEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue== ?

Comment: Just to make sure a single modifier key was pressed

Comment: So if I later wanted to check for more than one modifier key, the contains method would be more appropriate?

Comment: A code only answer with no explanation of how the answer supposedly answers the question is frowned upon. Update the answer to explain what was wrong and how this solves the problem.

Comment: What does that have to do with your answer which was posted before the other?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to put in a comment, but wasn't able to.

In case someone (like me) comes across this article in the future, Swift has changed a little since 2015.

**Swift 4:**

theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.command)

theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.option)

theEvent.modifierFlags.contains([.command, .option]) 
        NSLog("command and option keys down")

also; (.control) is for CTRL.

This is my particular code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.keyDown, handler: myKeyDownEvent)

}


func myKeyDownEvent(event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent {

    if (event.keyCode == 121) && event.modifierFlags.contains([.command, .option]) {

        //Do what you want when PGDN + cmd + alt is pressed

    }

    return event
}
```