# How to properly test against certain values in NSEventModifierFlags via Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

When using the `flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent)` method of the `NSResponder` class, how do I test against the `event.modifierFlags` option set for individual modifier keys being pressed/released?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking keyDown event.modifierFlags yields error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158513/checking-keydown-event-modifierflags-yields-error)

Comment: @EricAya I guess the title of my question was not worded properly: I should have asked how to properly test against certain values in `event.modifierFlags` via Swift. In Objective C one must use bitwise masking, but in Swift that's non-idiomatic and should instead use `event.modifierFlags.contains(_ member: NSEventModifierFlags)`, as I later have found out and have pointed out in my answer. This is an example when you need to deal with Cocoa in different ways based on what programming language you use. I hope this helps understanding my motivation behind asking a new question.

Comment: @Arcanelab Thank you for the explanation. I agree, in this specific case. No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, here I check for the `shift` key:

```
override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent)
{
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift)
    {
        // shift pressed
    }
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) == false
    {
        // shift released
    }
}
```